# Xamarin can't build portable class library - can't target necessary frameworks

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

We are using Xamarin for mobile apps development, however things are a bit complicated, when we try to share code. When someone makes changes to the project and you pull them, usually you are in for a bit of a headache regarding references.

With latest issue things got a bit stanger so I decided to post a question here in hope to resolve this.

It's the same project, two different computers, both using profile49, but my can't target all the frameworks.

Here are the images of the situation.

*On computer where it works*
[image: On computer where it works]

*On computer where it doesn't work*
[image: On computer where it doesn't work]

Maybe it's worth mentioning that both uses VS2012. Working computer uses windows 8 and not working 8.1. Both have Xamarin installend (iOS and Android).

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Are they both VS2012 Update 4 RTM? Latest version of Xamarin? etc.

Comment: My (not working) is (update 4 and newset version of Xamarin), can't currently check on the other computer, but I think it's as well. Interesting thing maybe is that if I look in c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile49\SupportedFrameworks\ 
I see only 2 files - Windows Phone 8.xml and .NET Framework 4.5.xml - which are exectly the ones that are selected when project is loaded . Shouldn't there be also Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: I have solved it. It seems that for some reason, my supported frameworks got modified (c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile49\SupportedFram‌​eworks\). Not really sure what caused this - it could be update to VS2012 - however reinstalling Xamarin fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that you installed Xamarin before Visual Studio or an update to Windows / Visual Studio replaced the entire `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable` directory, thus removing the `Xamarin.Android.xml` and `Xamarin.iOS.xml` files.

Reinstalling Xamarin fixes this, though repairing should work as well (go to Control Panel / Programs and Features, then right-click Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS and select "repair").

Comment: That was exectly what happend. I wrote it on comment under my question. Did not know about the repair thouh. I quess it's faster then reinstalling. I accepted your answer, to close this up. Thank you.